# Python Pandas: getting the entire row having maximum value of one column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning `Pandas` and stumble around finding the entire row of `Data frame` having maximum of one column

```
      A           B
0     Fruits     122
1     Veggies    23
2     Eggs       223
```

How to get the entire row where B is maximum

This is what I tried:
`df['B'].max()`, however this just gives me the index i.e. `2`. How to get the entire row such as 
`Eggs       223`. 
Can someone suggest one liner pls

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`argmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argmax.html) to get index of the maximum value and then pass it to [`iloc`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_yrufz6HKAhUHJnIKHQdqC-EQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.17.1%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.iloc.html&usg=AFQjCNGRd6Fb6DHL3kZ54D-eG8oZRBnvMg) to get your row:

```
In [195]: df.iloc[df.B.argmax()]
Out[195]:
A    Eggs
B     223
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Or if you prefer `list` you could use `tolist` method:

```
In [196]: df.iloc[df.B.argmax()].tolist()
Out[196]: ['Eggs', 223]
```